# XPages - opening a custom control causes Lotus Notes client to crash

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm using Lotus Notes 8.5.3 FP1 with the Extension Library. I have a custom control which causes the Lotus Notes client to crash each time I try to open that custom control in Domino Designer. Most custom controls and Xpages open without problems. How can I debug and solve this issue? I have already tried deinstalling and reinstalling the Extension Library but the problem remains. It's also not posssible to open XPages containing that custom control in a browser. This gives Error 500 HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception.

```
Started at: Tue May 06 13:13:23 2014
Ended   at: Tue May 06 13:13:41 2014
Time Spent: 00:00:18

Generated Messages:

   INFO (0): This NSD was generated due to a Domino shutdown hang.
         There will not be a FATAL thread.  Any processes/threads other than
         the main server thread and the server timeout thread which started
         this NSD should be examined to determine why they did not terminate
         when requested to do so.

   INFO (0): failed to match all of the Notes processes
   INFO (0): Directory Listing for Workspace Logs not generated (no such directory).
   INFO (0): No Directory Listings for FT (none were open).
   INFO (0): terminated process [nNOTESMM:  0e90]
   INFO (0): terminated process [ belnapi:  1054]
   INFO (0): terminated process [ belnapi:  01f0]
   INFO (0): terminated process [ nserver:  0b34]
   INFO (0): process [nSMDreal:  0d90] has already terminated
   INFO (0): Deleting pid.nbf
   WARNING (0): proc [nSMDreal:  0d90] terminated
   ERROR (44): unable to open file 'C:\Lotus\Domino\framework\rcp\rcplauncher.properties' - (2) No such file or directory
   ERROR (0): Couldn't open the rcplauncher.properties file using the path C:\Lotus\Domino\framework\rcp\rcplauncher.properties to locate the workspace directory.



Please send the following files:

NSD Log : D:\Lotus\Domino\data\IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT\nsd_W32I_chprone2_2014_05_06@13_13_23.log
```

Comment: Open the latest NSD in the IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder. Look for "FATAL THREAD" and post the stack. "Error 500" messages should be in the XPages.log in the IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder as well.

Comment: Thanks, I added the FATAL THREAD info to the question.

Comment: Although @DavidLeedy's comment is most likely, what you have is a hang and not a crash. You need to generate 3 NSDs and compare the stacks (Start menu under ibm/notes/support).  See: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24019151 for how to analyze them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your replies. I solved this problem by opening the Custom Controls with Domino Designer 9 on another PC. Somehow some syntax errors had occurred in the code. After removing these and cleaning the project, I was able to again work normally with designer 8.5.3

Answer (score 7):

I've seen this happen when something gets messed up with SourceControl.  Specifically using SourceTree.  I had a case where if you looked at the application in package explorer I ended up with some duplicates of design elements with "orig" on the end of the name.
so I'd have:
mPage.xsp
mPage.xsp.orig

Something like that. Designer did NOT like that.  Deleting all the orig files solved my particular problem.

If you're not using source control I'd copy the markup from the custom control and paste it into a brand new one.  Then delete the old one.  Be careful as copying the markup does not get any custom properties.

Answer (score 2):

Does the Custom Control contain other Custom Control(s) with lots of content? When you open a Custom Control in Domino Designer, it loads a visual representation of the contents. If there is a lot, it's possible that it could cause memory issues.

If this is the case, you would not be able to open an XPage containing the Custom Control.

For large Custom Controls I would recommend creating a Design Definition (Custom Control properties, immediately below Property Definition. This basically takes markup from an XPage of something to display instead. You can create a new XPage, create a layout of what you want to display instead of the full contents, then go to the source tab and copy everything. Thyen paste that into the box for Design Definition.

See the tooltip Custom Control in this project I did for OpenNTF http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Dijit.Tooltip%20Custom%20Control. The Design Definition basically tells it to display an image instead of the full Custom Control, and that image documents what needs to be set.